# pandas filtering in front of specific string

Tags: python, string, pandas, filter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOTvV.jpg)

As you see in yellow column(col name='식품이름')
some have @, some are not. 
I want to delete ~~@ and remain only last words. 
SO, i coded like

```
import pandas as pd 
pr1 = pd.read_csv('D:\\py_project\\.vscode\\wdata.csv', encoding='utf-8')

for i in pr1['식품이름']:
        if '@' in i:
            i = i.split('@')[-1]
```

but the problem is how can I edit and apply at real file.
If I print, it works well but it didn't saved in raw file.
How can I solve it??

Comment: `pr1['식품이름'] = pr1['식품이름'].str.split("@").str[-1]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think condition is not necessary, use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with select last strings by indexing:

```
pr1 = pd.DataFrame({'식품이름':[' ~~@text','ssds','wew@efs']})

print (pr1)
       식품이름
0   ~~@text
1      ssds
2   wew@efs

pr1['new'] =  pr1['식품이름'].str.split("@").str[-1]
print (pr1)
       식품이름   new
0   ~~@text  text
1      ssds  ssds
2   wew@efs   efs
```

Comment: i did your code, but it's partially work.. i hope pr1 show entirely, but change value which contains '@' and save or create new entire file. but i got a big help. thanks!!

Comment: @유승우 - Can you explain more?

Comment: i mean.. i want to change only @ part and exist rest of all.